# Particles attracting each other

Tags: particles

I'd like create a system of particles that attract each other with a force directly proportional to the product of their mass and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them...yes like gravity makes planets orbit around stars, galaxies attract each other etc.
How can be done?

Comment: You could use *Force Fields* rollout in the particle system settings to make particles affect themselves. The only and the main problem would be to choose force field type. *Force* type affects similarly but with strength not depending on the distance and mass.

Answer (score 0):

In the particle system, under *Field Weights*, set *Gravity* to zero.
Still in the particle system, under *Force Field* settings, set the *Type* to *Force*, set *Strength* to a value below zero and check the *Gravitation* box.

Using this I managed to form particles into a planet, complete with an orbiting moon.

I also used the Molecular Addon and had to increase the damping under *Activate Self Collision*, otherwise you just have a big bang and particles flying off in all directions.